# How to get just the token so I can use it in my HTTP header

Tags: angular

Im trying to include the access token to my HTTP request.  I saved it to local storage and it saved as an object . How can I retrieve just the token so I can put it in my HTTP Authorization header

This is my login component.ts

```
       import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
      import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
       import { Router } from '@angular/router'
         import {LoginServiceService} from 'src/app/login-service.service'
      import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

        @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
      })
      export class LoginComponent implements OnInit
        {

    response: any;
      constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, public 
  LoginService:LoginServiceService) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {

   }

    login(newFormdata:any)
       {

      this.LoginService.login(newFormdata).subscribe((data) =>
      {
      console.log(data)
      localStorage.setItem("token",JSON.stringify(data))
      this.router.navigate(['facility-list'])
      })
      }  
      }

 This is my Login service

 export class LoginServiceService {

  constructor( private http:HttpClient,private router:Router) { }

  login(information:any)
  {
  return this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/api/login", information)
  }
  }

  This is the http interceptor

   export class AppinterceptorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

   constructor() { }
   token = localStorage.getItem("'token")
   intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>>
   {
   let tokenizedRequest = request.clone({
   setHeaders: {
     Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.token
   }
  })

return next.handle(tokenizedRequest);

 }
}
```

Please send me a message or comment if you have answer . I know that this is an easy question . I ahighly appreciate your responses guys . Thank you

Comment: type mistaken `token = localStorage.getItem("token")` extra `'` was added

Answer (score 0):

First, `getItem("'token")` has an ' too much, it needs to be `getItem("token")`.

Secondly, you only read the token from localStorage when the Interceptor is created.

Have you tried to load the token in the intercept function itself?

```
   intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>>
   {
   if (!this.token) { this.token = localStorage.getItem("token"); }
   let tokenizedRequest = request.clone({
   setHeaders: {
     Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.token
   }
```

That should work. Also, instead of using the localStorage to get / set the token, you might want to use a Service that is injected into both the Interceptor and the LoginService, such as a TokenService.